# WebBrowser control content width/height

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm having difficulties trying to programmitcally determine the width and height of a webbrowser based on the contents of a fully loaded page. I need this information to capture a screenshot of the webpage.

This occures within a button click event

```
wbNY.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.website.com"), "_self");
wbNY.DocumentCompleted += wbNY_DocumentCompleted;
```

This is my document completed code

```
private void wbNY_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url == wbNY.Url)
    {
        if (wbNY.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            DoPageChecks();
        }
    }
}
```

Within DoPageChecks I call this method

```
TakeScreenshot(wbNY);
```

This is my TakeScreenshot method

```
protected void TakeScreenshot(WebBrowser wb)
{
    Size pageSize = new Size(wb.Document.Window.Size.Width,wb.Document.Window.Size.Height)
}
```

My screenshot code works fine, so I'm just showing everything up to the point where I'm trying to get the height and width of the webbrowser contents, so that I can take a screenshot with the correct dimensions.

I've also tried

```
    Size pageSize = new Size(wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width,wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height)
```

But this also isn't giving the correct values.

More specifically, height is coming over as 0, or a sometimes ~20px, when the real result should be closer to 800px+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately I went ahead and found mshtml had the tools to obtain the width/height.

The final screenshot method:

```
protected void TakeScreenshot(WebBrowser wb)
{
    mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 docs2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)wbNY.Document.DomDocument;
    mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 docs3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)wbNY.Document.DomDocument;
    mshtml.IHTMLElement2 body2 = (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)docs2.body;
    mshtml.IHTMLElement2 root2 = (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)docs3.documentElement;

    int width = Math.Max(body2.scrollWidth, root2.scrollWidth);
    int height = Math.Max(root2.scrollHeight, body2.scrollHeight);

    // Resize the control to the exact size to display the page. Also, make sure scroll bars are disabled
    wb.Width = width;
    wb.Height = height;

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
    wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
    bitmap.Save(SaveImgDirectory + filename);
}
```

Comment: cool, OOI did your bitmap actually contain the correct image, when I tried it the image was just white.

Comment: Yea, it worked perfectly. If you're getting a white image, it could be because you're not properly waiting for the full page load. See my original post to see how I determine when I can finally grab the image.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get [ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx), they return the rendered height and width of the [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx), which is what you want if you are taking a screenshot.

Comment: I don't see those specific properties, but wb.Width/Height returns the specified width/height of the control in the designer. I'm not taking a screenshot in the typical sense, I'm creating a bitmap image of the contents within the webbrowser control. The problem is I can't get the dimensions of the page regardless the static size of the webbrowser control. If I set the control to be 100px by 100px, thats the size of my screenshot, cutting off large portions of the full page. Since I don't know the exact dimension I need on a page by page basis, I need to determine these values on the fly

Comment: @user1691808 ah, my mistake.  I think you may have an [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) in hand rather than a Window, hence the lack of those useful properties.  Are you WPF, Winforms or Silverlight?

Comment: @user1691808 ok, I see via your solution it's not a normal 'screenshot'.  I knocked up an app to see what props would give you the width and height, in the normal sense, wb.Size.Height and wb.Size.Width worked for me.  I can see you would need more than that though.

Comment: @user1691808, my code:  I displayed the height and width so I could see what happened when I resized the window.  OOI the bitmap saved wasn't correct.  
`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    int height = webBrowser1.Size.Height;  
    int width = webBrowser1.Size.Width;  
    textBoxHeight.Text = height.ToString();  
    textBoxWidth.Text = width.ToString();  

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);  
    webBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));  
    bitmap.Save("test.bmp");  
}`